# How to get all characters from 240 character to the last character?

Tags: javascript

Currently I am trying to implement a "Read more" & "Read less" buttons for user reviews which are too long. Right now I display the first 240 characters of the review thanks to

`review.text.slice(0,240)`

but now I need to somehow get all the characters from symbol 240 to the last one. I assume slice() would be used again but I have no idea how to find the last symbol. If I knew how long every review will be, this would be easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will slice starting at `0` and ending at `240`. If you leave off the last parameter, it will slice everything after that:

```
review.text.slice(240);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice, you can use `review.text.slice(-1)` to get the last parameter.